# Spring RabbitMQ Failed to read schema document

Tags: spring, spring-rabbit

```
**Spring not able to read XML Schema document for rabbit MQ**

I am trying to run Spring MDP application on windows 8 using Java 8.
I have configured spring file and defined xml schema document for rabbitMQ.
```

Below is my Spring context file which I am using and I have defined all the beans. :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit    http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.6.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-4.0.xsd">

I am getting error when trying to start the application  :

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 159; columnNumber: 64; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.6.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
   at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
```

The application is working for all the other xml schema document except Rabbit mq.I have tried changing rabbitmq schema document version as well but it seems none of them is working.

Edit: 
I am not using maven. I have included spring-rabbit-2.0.jar in my classpath. enter image description [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/801v6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of spring-rabbit?

I suspect it's not 1.6.x.

Best practice is to not use versioned schemas and Spring will the resolve the correct version based on the `spring.schemas` in the META-INF in the jar.

Use `http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd`

and `spring-jms.xsd`.

Comment: Is `spring-rabbit` on the classpath? Add your POM to the question.

Comment: `1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.` - if #3, it could be a corrupt jar.

Comment: I am not using maven.i have included spring rabbit jar in my classmate.Jar is not corrupt.i have tried different jars as well

Comment: Well then there is definitely something wrong with your classpath; try running with JVM arg `-verbose` and watch the class loading activity. If you still can't figure it out, post the log someplace like pastebin or a GitHub gist. It's generally best to use maven or gradle to manage all your dependencies rather than rolling your own class path.

Comment: `> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect` - looks like you are somehow fetching the schema from the internet; perhaps you have a firewall problem. But fetching it from the internet should happen because Spring will get it from the jar instead using `META-INF/spring-schemas`. There is definitely something fishy about your project.

Comment: I just saw your deleted answer; the spring-rabbit-2.0.jar doesn't contain the 1.6 schema - are you sure you tried without a version?

Comment: Edit the question and show the new stack trace without the version and, like I said, try `-verbose`.

Comment: There are many xml documents but I didn't get any firewall with them .infact when I tried to access schema documents from browser ,I  am able to do so.Probably I will use maven for that and let u know my results

Comment: There is no way we should be trying to get the schema from the internet, so something is wrong.

Comment: That's the standards syntax that we use for schemalocation in spring context file.I will try with maven and let you know my results

Comment: You were right about my classpath.I added all the dependencies in maven and the error is gone .wow.Thanks a lot